# Boost spirit stack overflow exception in recursive rule

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I have the following simple grammar:

```
expr_ = lit("+") > expr_
            | qi::uint_
            ;
```

Basically, it's simply ignoring `+` signs in front of an int.

The following input causes a stack overflow:

```
+++ ...(~195 more + chars )... ++1
```

I understand that the recursivity in the rule would indeed cause this behavior, but is there a way to avoid such exceptions (kind of indicating that the rule is tail recursive somehow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are probably aware, you can rewrite your rule to remove the recursion:

```
expr_ = *lit("+") > qi::uint_;
```

As to your question about tail recursion, basically the answer is no.

Comment: Thanks, I actually did overlook using `*`